# LineChartView using Charts Library Swift

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I am using LineChart from https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

I have a lot of data displayed on the Y-axis so the labels values aren't displayed cause there is too much data and which I'm fine with since I want to show only the highest and lowest value on the chart, but I didn't find any way to achieve it.

Can someone give me a hint?

[image]